# Best user interface for category and Items management

Tags: android, user-interface

For an unreleased FOSS project, I have two sets of data for managing expenses:
a) **categories** : e.g. food, clothing, health_care, education etc. 
b) **items** : e.g. burger, soda, shirt etc.

I have to provide the user the following operations.
1) Add/Edit/Delete an item.
2) Add/Edit/Delete a category.
3) Move single/multiple expense items to a category

What is the best UI design for these operations fitting in one Activity?

I am thinking of using two Spinners and seven Buttons.
But the user experience will be poor in that way.

Comment: reduced complexity of the question

Comment: See the documentation about [lists](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists.html) and [list controls](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists-controls.html),